# Get WPF ContextMenu to show on Winforms NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, notifyicon

I am using the Winforms `NotifyIcon` as there is no WPF Version, I am also using the ContextMenu tutorial here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html

And I will be using the mouse placement code found in the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8cdd4ef1-d31e-42ef-a30e-7b482c0fa163/

My main problem is, the method:

```
private void OpenContextMenu(FrameworkElement element)
{
    if( element.ContextMenu != null )
    {
       element.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = element;
       element.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

How is it used? Can anyone tell me what steps I will need to do just to get this to show up for my NotifyIcon

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to open the contextmenu by right-clicking the NotifyIcon?  Is it an option to simply assign a WinForms ContextMenu to the NotifyIcon.ContextMenu property?

Comment: Yes I am using the right click handler, but I don't want to use the win forms ContextMenu as I want to be able to customize my own ContextMenu with Xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one out myself, it does the job and very easy to implement.

http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2007/10/15/a-wpf-wrapper-around-windows-form-notifyicon.aspx

Answer (score 2):

CodePlex has a [WPF version of NotifyIcon](http://wpfcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyIcon&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=wpfcontrib).  That might meet your needs better.

Comment: Thanks for the info but the Visual Studio Solution doesn't open the project correctly, and I don't know if it uses some other library, which I'm trying to avoid.