# Is there a way to convert a Controls.ContextMenu to a Forms.ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, contextmenu

I have a context menu defined in my WPF XAML that looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static props:Resources.MenuItem1}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'm using a `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` "myIcon" for my tray icon because it's so trivial to setup and use and because there seems to be no standard MSFT WPF equivalent. Unfortunately I get a casting exception when I call

```
this.myIcon.ContextMenu = (ContextMenu)this.Resources["MyMenu"];
```

because they're obviously not the same `ContextMenu` class. Is there a way to simply convert from the `Controls.ContextMenu` to a `Forms.ContextMenu`?

I'd prefer not to handle the right click mouse event of the notify icon by manually bringing up the context menu defined in my XAML. The reason being I suspect that the right click mouse event is not sent when the user uses the context menu key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the controls are for completely different platforms (Winforms vs WPF).  There is no "conversion" between the two.

Either use [a different version of NotifyIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539672) that supports WPF or write a "conversion" that translates the items of the WPF context menu and adds them to the Winforms context menu.

Answer (score 1):

So, I case anybody is curious. I ended up implementing a converter.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyApp
{
    class NotifyIconEx
    {
        #region Data
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon _notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        #endregion // Data

        #region Properties
        public Icon Icon
        {
            get { return _notifyIcon.Icon; }
            set { _notifyIcon.Icon = value; }
        }
        public ContextMenu ContextMenu
        {
            private get { return null; }
            set
            {
                _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
                foreach (var item in value.Items)
                {
                    if (item is MenuItem)
                    {
                        var menuItem = item as MenuItem;
                        var toolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
                        toolStripMenuItem.Click += (s, e) => menuItem.RaiseEvent(new System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs(MenuItem.ClickEvent));
                        toolStripMenuItem.Text = menuItem.Header as string;
                        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(toolStripMenuItem);
                    }
                    else if (item is Separator)
                    {
                        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public bool Visible
        {
            get { return _notifyIcon.Visible; }
            set { _notifyIcon.Visible = value; }
        }
        #endregion // Properties

        #region API
        public void ShowBalloonTip(int timeout)
        {
            _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(timeout);
        }
        public void ShowBalloonTip(int timeout, string tipTitle, string tipText, System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon tipIcon)
        {
            _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(timeout, tipTitle, tipText, tipIcon);
        }
        #endregion // API
    }
}
```